# Liferay 7 Session not found

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I used liferay-session-overrid.js and, when the user is not active, I do `AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.logout (httpRequest, httpResponse)`
But sometimes such an error with not found session is reproduced
Can i fix this problem?
This is rarely done, but remains a problem.
The error appears when I try to do on the filter request.getSession()

```
    2019-12-11 20:29:32.704 INFO  [default task-7][PreLogoutAction:19] PreLogoutAction was executed!
    2019-12-11 20:29:32.705 INFO  [default task-7][PreLogoutAction:20] User is empty
    2019-12-11 20:29:32.773 INFO  [default task-23][PreLogoutAction:19] PreLogoutAction was executed!
    2019-12-11 20:29:32.779 INFO  [default task-23][PreLogoutAction:20] User is empty
    2019-12-11 20:29:32.840 ERROR [default task-14][VirtualHostFilter:375] javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to execute request
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to execute request
            at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:204)
 2019-12-11 20:29:32.844 ERROR [default task-14][RestoringCartFilter:62] java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session not found ojlT9glxtyQEXskve3QxttVXcsVbrkI86VojtnBc
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session not found ojlT9glxtyQEXskve3QxttVXcsVbrkI86VojtnBc
            at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.getAttribute(InMem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not control that. There is always a possibility that a session does not exists on the server. It could be because your script was too late or because the session was removed in some other way you didn't detect. You'd have to account for that possibility and deal with the error on the frontend side.